# Lookup Column - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, lookup-column

Is there any way to link parent site and sub sites?

Problem: I have one list on Parent site and I have a few other lists on sub sites. I am trying to create lookup columns in the parent site list to obtain the data from the sub-site lists. Is this possible? Please advise. Is this an out of the box feature on Sharepoint? Or do I need to get SharePoint designer and infopath involved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This isn't possible with Out of the box SharePoint features, you need to customize it..

Comment: Could you please provide additional info? Customize it how?

Comment: You could do something in infopath; use list lookups on the sub sites and filter on the parent somehow. I would probably write an html/js view using the JSOM/REST API and maybe knockout or angular to manage the html binding but if you're not developmentally-inclined you can hammer something together with infopath/designer as you mentioned

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you can reverse your requirement where the lookups are at a higher site than the list consuming them, then you can use site columns to accomplish this.  Site columns only exist on the current site and it's subsites.

Comment: Thanks! But I still remained confused. I have 5 sites: A, B, C, D and E. The first four contain lists that I need to use in the last one. What you are saying is if A, B, C and D are at a higher site then the list in E then the lookup is possible?

Comment: See if this article helps clarify things:  https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Create-a-SharePoint-Lookup-Column-to-Another-Site.aspx